# On the proof that there exists a strictly increasing function $f : \text{cf}(A) \to A$ such that $\text{rng}(f)$ is cofinal in $A$

Tags: set-theory, transfinite-recursion

I am looking at the following theorem in a set of notes:

> **Theorem 12.48**. Suppose that $(A, <)$ is a simple order with no largest element. Then there is a strictly increasing function $f : \text{cf}(A) \to A$ such that $\text{rng}(f)$ is cofinal in $A$.
>
> **Proof.** Let $X$ be a cofinal subset of $A$ of size $\text{cf}(A)$, and let $g$ be a bijection from $\text{cf}(A)$ onto $X$. We define a function $f:\text{cf}(A) \to X$ by recursion, as follows. If $f(\beta) \in X$ has been defined for all $\beta<\alpha$, where $\alpha< \text{cf}(A)$, then $\{f(\beta) : \beta < \alpha\}$ has size less than $\text{cf}(A)$, and hence it is not cofinal. Hence there is an $a \in A$ such that $f(\beta) < a$ for all $\beta<\alpha$. We let $f(\alpha)$ be an element of $X$ such that $a, g(\alpha) \leq f(\alpha)$. Clearly $f$ is strictly increasing. If $a \in A$, choose $\alpha < \text{cf}(A)$ such that $a ≤ g(\alpha)$. Then $a \leq f(\alpha)$.

**Questions:**

1. I don't see where the assumption of no largest element came into play?
2. Why do we map $f$ into $X$ and not simply into $A$? (i.e. let $f(\alpha)=\max\{a,g(\alpha)\}$). It seems to me we need the axiom of choice to choose $f(\alpha)$ in $X$.
3. Do we need the axiom of choice to choose $a$?

Comment: I assume 'simple' means the same thing as 'total' here? What is your precise definition of cofinality? You ask about the axiom of choice here, but it would seem that there's already some use of choice implicit in the question.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Indeed simple means total in the notes. The definition of $\text{cf}(A)$ is the smallest cardinality of a cofinal subset of $A$. Yes I think AC is needed already to define $\text{cf}(A)$.

Comment: Okay, so we're tacitly assuming choice then in the premise of the question, then? (Not that this completely invalidates your questions about it.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Yes AC is assumed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are right. It doesn't. It's just that an order with a maximum has a cofinality of $1$. That's not interesting and we don't need to pay any attention to that case.
2. Choosing the maximum between two points in a linear order does not require choice. Of course, choice was used so heavily already in that $X$ can be well-ordered, and so on. What's one more use amongst friends?
3. Well, if you know there is a cofinal subset which is well-orderable (note that a subset is cofinal if, essentially, it is unbounded), then there is no need for the axiom of choice. We can just work inside such a subset. But in general, given an arbitrary linear order the existence of a well-orderable cofinal subset requires using the axiom of choice. For example, no such subset can be found in a linearly ordered infinite Dedekind finite set.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So regarding 2 there is no need in the proof to impose $f$ to have range contained in $X$?

Comment: @Alphie No, just recursively let $f(\alpha)$ be strictly greater than everything in $\{f(\beta): \beta< \alpha\}\cup\{g(\alpha)\}$ for $\alpha < \operatorname{cf}(A)$. There is such an element in $X,$ which has a well-ordering, so one could avoid using choice at this juncture by picking from $X$, but maybe not much point doing that. We could rephrase to "if $\kappa$ is the least size of a well-orderable cofinal subset of $A,$ then there is a cofinal set of order-type $\kappa$", which would work in ZF and you'd need to pick from $X$.

Comment: @Alphie: You don't *have* to, but if you are looking for an upper bound on size, why shouldn't you? Also, in some cases you might actually have to. What if the $A$ is a regular cardinal? Then the cofinal subset might just be $A$ itself.